# Структура проекта django и настройка путей

Tags: python, django

Как грамотно прописать пути к static-файлам и шаблонам в settings.py?
Туда ли я положил папку templates?

```
/var/www/myproject
├── static_content
│   └── static
│       ├── img
│       ├── css
│       ├── js
│       ├── templates
│       │   ├── main.html
│       │   ├── app1
│       │   │   ├── template1.html
│       │   │   └── template2.html
│       │   └── app2
│       │       └── template1.html
│       └── media
│           └── img
├── src
│   └── myproject
│       ├── manage.py
│       └── myproject
│           ├── settings.py       
│           ├── urls.py
│           └── wsgi.py   
├── logs
└── env
    ├── bin
    │   ├── activate
    │   ├── activate.csh
    │   ├── activate.fish
    │   ├── django-admin
    │   ├── django-admin.py
    │   ├── easy_install
    │   ├── easy_install-3.4
    │   ├── pip
    │   ├── pip3
    │   ├── pip3.4
    │   ├── python -> python3.4
    │   ├── python3 -> python3.4
    │   └── ...
    ├── include
    ├── lib
    └── docs
```

settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for firstapp project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '...'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app1',
    'app2',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
                '/var/www/myproject/static_content/static/templates',
                '/var/www/myproject/static_content/static/templates/app1',
                '/var/www/myproject/static_content/static/templates/app2',
            ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,

         'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [            
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-RU'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static_content/')
#STATICFILES_DIRS = (
#    ('static', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")),
#)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы неправильно определили BASE_DIR, из вашего кода она будет указывать на `/var/www/myproject/src/myproject`, если нужно указывать на `/var/www/myproject`, то вам следует написать примерно так:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..', '..'))
```

в настройке `STATIC_URL` указывается только урл для браузера, для указания папки нужно использовать настройку `STATICFILES_DIRS`, для вашего случая будет так:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_content', 'static'),
)
```

Папка `templates` в папке для статики не нужна, её лучше поместить в корень проекта (тогда можно чуть проще указать путь), или в папку `src`.
Соответственну нужно поменять настройку до папки с шаблонами:

```
TEMPLATES = [{
    ...
    'DIRS': [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
    ]
    ...
}]
```